# ASP.Net MVC RC2 Ajax.Form becoming Ajax.BeginForm stopped working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We just upgraded from TCP 4 to RC 2 of the MVC framework for .net.  The following code, which worked, now just does a regular post (ie. navigates to the create page):

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "LEEDBoardItem", new AjaxOptions()
   {
    UpdateTargetId = "LEEDBoardDisplay",
    HttpMethod = "POST"
   }))
{ %>
 <%= Html.Hidden("Selling_Color_Name", ViewData.Model.SelectedColor == null ? "" : ViewData.Model.SelectedColor.SellingColorName) %>
 <%= Html.Hidden("Selling_Color_Number", ViewData.Model.SelectedColor == null ? "" : ViewData.Model.SelectedColor.SellingColorNumber) %>
 <%= Html.Hidden("Selling_Style_Name", ViewData.Model.Style_Name) %>
 <%= Html.Hidden("Selling_Style_Number", ViewData.Model.Style_Number) %>
 <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
 <% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/LEEDBoardItem/Form.ascx", new LEEDBoardItem());%>
 <input type="submit" value="New" />
<% } %>
```

Anyone have similar problems with RC2?  I can switch to an ActionLink, but I'd rather use a form post.

Thanks!
Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only thing I can think of is make sure you grab the latest .js files from RC2 and put them in your project and reference them properly.

Comment: Where would I find those latest files?  I searched my drive after installing, but it didn't find files with a high enough version number.

Comment: I created a new project and copied the files from there.  It looks like the problem was that I had jquery1.2.6 and it need 1.3.1.